# How to stop for loop from printing results in R

Tags: r, function, loops

I'm trying to loop through integers 1:1000 comparing the result of a function I've created with an R function. Specifically, I have:

```
floor.log2 = function(n) {
  x = 1
  i = 0
  while (x <= n) {
    x = 2*x
    i = i + 1
  }
  print(i-1)
}
```

And I want to compare with:

```
floor(log(n, base = 2))
```

Every comparison loop I've created ends up printing each index 1:1000 - what is a succinct way to compare results for 1:1000 in these functions without R printing the indices?

Comment: You could start by removing the `print` statement

Comment: @kdopen wow. I'm actually not sure how I didn't catch that. Thank you.

Comment: and then you need to actually return something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would modify the existing function you wrote to:

```
floor.log2 = function(n) {
 x = 1
 i = 0
 while (x <= n) {
   x = 2*x
   i = i + 1
}
return(i-1)
}
```

To test:

```
 iter <- 100  # How long you would like to test for 
 vec1 <- c()  # Container of your custom function
 vec2 <- c()  # Container for the comparison function

for(i in 1:iter) {
   vec1[i] <- floor.log2(i)
   vec2[i] <- floor(log(i, base = 2))
 }
```

Finally:

```
all(vec1 == vec2)
```

Comment: You could improve this by [vectorizing](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Vectorize.html) the `floor.log2` function to avoid using the `for` loop: `floor.log2_V <- Vectorize(floor.log2, vectorize.args = 'n')`.

Comment: Thanks for the information regarding `Vectorize()`. I have not run across that in the wild.